# With Electron/Node.js, how do I implement simple sequential code asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, electron, wait

I am working on a project where my Electron App interacts with a physical device using serial commands, via [`serialport`](https://github.com/node-serialport/node-serialport). The app sends a string to the device, the device executes the command (which can take ~30s) and then sends back a string to signify completion and results from that operation.

My goal is to automate a series of actions. For that, basically the following needs to be done **asynchronously**, so that the render thread doesn't get blocked:

1. Start a loop
2. Send a string to the device
3. Wait until a specific response comes back
4. Tell the render thread about the response, so it can update the UI
5. **Afterwards**, repeat with the next string.

Actually, multiple different commands need to be send in each loop cycle, and between each one the app has to wait for a specific string from the device.

This is kind of related to my last question, *[What's the correct way to run a function asynchronously in Electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795352/whats-the-correct-way-to-run-a-function-asynchronously-in-electron)*. From that, I know I should use web workers to run something asynchronously. However, my plan turned out to involve more problems than I anticipated, and I wanted to ask what would be a good way to implement this, having the whole plan in mind and not just a certain aspect of it.

I am especially not sure how to make the worker work with `serialport`. The serial device it needs to interact  with  is a child of the render process, so sending commands will probably be done over web worker messages. But I have no idea on how to make the worker wait for a specific response from the device.

---

(Since this question is of a more general nature, I am unsure whether I should provide some code snippets. If this is to general, I can try to write some pseudo code to make my problem more clear.)

Comment: Unless you want to do some heavy processing of binary data, your best bet would be to look into [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). If you want to do real heavylifthing multithreading, then node/electron is probably not the best tool for this project.

Comment: @TLP There is no heavy processing involved, all the app needs to do is send commands, wait for their execution and display results. I know about Promises, but I don't see how they could help me here. Can you explain?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `serialport` but from a quick look at it, I see it works with promises, so if you send a string to it, it should respond with a promise. I'll post some code in the answer section to show how I think this could work.

Comment: @TLP Ah, thanks! :)
The problem is that the answer from the device is not the resolved promise from sending the serial. It comes in later and can be catched via an event from `serialport`. So I kind of need to hook to that event in the render thread, and when something comes in, communicate it to the loop. And when it matches what the loop is waiting for, it will continue execution.

Comment: You can have an event listener resolving a promise for you.

Comment: That's interesting! Did not know it was possible like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a promise-based approach like this:

```
let promiseChain = Promise.resolve();

waitForEvent = function(){
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        event.on("someEvent", (eventData => {
            resolve(eventData)
         }))
    })

}

while(someLoopCondition) {
    promiseChain = promiseChain
    .then(sendToSerialPort(someString))
    .then(waitForEvent)
    .then(result=>{
        updateUI(result)
    })
}
```

Comment: @TLP Thanks, that seems like the correct way. One additional question: is it possible to abort this promise chain (e. g. from an event), once it is kicked off?

Comment: @Bergi Why is that better?

Comment: @jmb Because it removes the listener when the promise is getting resolved.

Comment: @Bergi I see! Thanks, will do ;)